Is there a way to release target membership when installing pod?
I always successfully built after the pod install, releasing the target membership of the mm file.
However, this time, we took this opportunity to introduce Xcode Cloud, which caused problems.
Is there a way to turn off target membership when installing pod? Or is there a problem that I need to set up more when using xcode cloud?
#!/bin/sh
brew update
brew install cocoapods
pod install

When using Xcode Cloud, the target membership cannot be released while writing the code in the ci_post_clone file, and the error continues to occur.
